# Eagerly loaded module - Imported or Exported in core module?

Tags: javascript, angular

In order to make my AppModule cleaner, I imported an eagerly loaded feature module in the CoreModule, which is imported (once) in the AppModule.

What i've found interesting, is that the app works by either exporting or importing the feature module in the CoreModule. Can anyone explain the difference? What's the correct way?

Comment: I have a youtube video that goes through some of the details of using Angular modules here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o

Answer (score 3):

Well, if there's a feature(mostly a declarable like a Component, Directive or Pipe) that you have in that `FeatureModule` and you want to use it in your `CoreModule`(which you've imported in your `AppModule`) or `AppModule`, you'll have to export it from your `CoreModule` as well.

If you export something from a Module it would be available to use in a Module that you import that Module in.

And if you export that module from the module that you've imported it in, you'll be able to use the exported module's features in the module that you're importing this module in.

Let's take for eg, an example with a `CoreModule`, an `AppModule` and a `FeatureModule`.

The `FeatureModule` has a `FeatureComponent` that's declared in it. If you want to use this `FeatureComponent` in the `CoreModule`, you'll have to export the `FeatureComponent` from the `FeatureModule` and then import the `FeatureModule` in your `CoreModule`.

Now if you want to use the `FeatureCompoent` in your `AppModule` as well. you can simply `export` the `FeatureModule` from the `CoreModule`. And since you've already imported the `CoreModule` in the `AppModule` you'll have access to all the exported members of the `CoreModule` and `FeatureModule` is one of them.

Here's what [**Angular's Docs**](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#exports) say, to help you understand better:

> The set of components, directives, and pipes declared in this NgModule that can be used in the template of any component that is part of an NgModule that imports this NgModule. Exported declarations are the module's public API.
>
> A declarable belongs to one and only one NgModule. A module can list another module among its exports, in which case all of that module's public declaration are exported.
>
> Declarations are private by default. If this ModuleA does not export UserComponent, then only the components within this ModuleA can use UserComponent.
>
> ModuleA can import ModuleB and also export it, making exports from ModuleB available to an NgModule that imports ModuleA.